# Snippet Easy Table Filter -

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using this Snippet http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/easy-table-filter

I would like for the menu items under Pagado's category to be selected/filtered and those be the only ones to show when landing on the home page without the user having to click on Pagado's button.

At the moment all of the menu items show from all categories / buttons and Pagado has to be clicked on in order to filter the menu.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include any relevant code in your post. This makes sure the code is always available together with your question as well as making it more convenient for any people trying to answer your question.

Comment: Your URL comes up with a 404

Comment: Sorry! I bumped a number just before copying the url.  http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/easy-table-filter